# EText Template: Count of rows not resetting at each Level

Tags: bi-publisher

Tool: Oracle BI Publisher
Template Type: EText
Problem: Count of rows for each person not getting reset from the 2nd Person onward

I are trying to get a count of the rows generated for each Person, but the count keeps increasing from the 2nd Person as shown in bold below:

Note: The second person (person number = 23456 should have had 2 printed instead of 5)

12345
John
Doe       3
**23456

John      5

34567

Jane

Doe       8

45678

Jane      10

56789

John

Jane      13**

Attaching the sample XML and Template that we are using as well as the sample output[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHQVm.png), [Sample XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Oki.png), [Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUWhP.png) any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The counts will definitely keep increasing, whether you decide to print it on the report or not.  I think you will have to change the way you are calculating the count to a formula, with if conditions, instead of cumulative counts.

```
example psuedo code: IF(PERSON_NUMBER IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) + IF(FIRST_NAME IN ('JOHN','JANE') THEN 1 ELSE 0) + IF(LAST_NAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0)
```

This will evaluate the count for each record without adding to the counts of the previous record.